# What's the future of complex touch gestures on Unix?

Tags: touchpad, touch-screen, mouse-gestures

The standard (only?) method of utilizing complex mouse/trackpad/pen gestures on Linux is [Easystroke](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/wiki). Before anyone mentions touchegg/libinput-gestures and similar, they serve a different purpose. Those support very simple gestures (swipe up, swipe down) and multitouch variants thereoff.

However easystroke supports complex gestures. For example you could draw an @ symbol, or a s shape, and each of those would produce a different result.

Unfortunately, easystroke itself hasn't had any activity since 2014, with the last release being 2013. It still works, but there's no response on the activity tracker, the author probably having moved on. With the shift to wayland, are any projects actively looking at this niche? Or is this a capability which will probably just go away in the future.

Comment: This is a fantastic topic for discussion and I'd be VERY interested in hearing some of the results.  However, I am dubious that it can be definitively answered *by anyone* aside from a time traveler.  It appears to be a opener *for discussion* rather than a question with a single specific answer.  As such, I must sadly vote to close it and eagerly request you bring up the subject in chat.  :)

Comment: With the scattered nature of Open Source I was hoping someone would point out that "hey, this project exists which is aiming for wayland support" or "kernel support for this is going away". That would be the answer, more about what the current status is.